# What does "<<" stand for in C#?

Tags: c#

What does << do in this piece of code?

```
[Serializable]
[Flags]
public enum SiteRoles
{
    User = 1 << 0,
    Admin = 1 << 1,
    Helpdesk = 1 << 2
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134204/multiple-ways-to-define-c-enums-with-flags-attribute/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Bitwise shifting](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpShiftOperators.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

It means bitshift left, so:

```
int i = 1 << 2;

// 0000 0001 (1)
// shifted left twice
// 0000 0100 (4)
```

A left bitshift is analogous to multiplying by two, and a right bitshift acts as a divide by two.

Bitshifts are useful because they convey semantics better when working with bitmasks and they are (on x86 at least) faster than multiplication

Comment: +1, for the commented example!

Comment: Shouldn't the decision whether to shift, multiply or add be left to the JITter?

Answer (score 5):

[Bitshifting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) Just like in C++

Comment: I think the confusion stems from `std::ostream` ...

Answer (score 1):

[Bitwise Shifting](http://weblogs.asp.net/alessandro/archive/2007/10/02/bitwise-operators-in-c-or-xor-and-amp-amp-not.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It is a Bitwise shift.

`Admin = 1 << 1` means one's binary value move to left one bit.

The result is

`Admin = 2`