# Bitset Intialization C++

Tags: c++, bitset

I know this initialization: `bitset<20>`.

But what does this initialization mean: `bitset<1<<20>`?

Comment: `1<<20` means 2 raised to  power 20 or as @Quimbly said 1 left shifted by 20 bits

Comment: `1<<20`  is a number, and is in the same position as `20` in the first example. I'm guessing that you haven't encountered the shift operator `<<` in its original habitat before.

Comment: See [C++: what does (a<<b) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983078/c-what-does-ab-mean)

Answer (score 1):

> But what this initialization means?

Parsing headache for the compiler perhaps.

You can use equivalent snippets: `bitset< 1<<20 >` - i.e. `1` left-shifted by  20 bits - `bitset<1048576>`

Comment: Pedantically saving 1 character to type.

Comment: `1<<20` shows more clearly your intent to future devs; it's not pedantic.

Comment: @Casey what is clearer? `1<<20` or `1048576`. In fact spaces should always be padded around binary operators so it should be `1 << 20` so it'll be longer

Comment: @phuclv Since the values are known at compile time, it's more clear to give `1048576` or `1<<20` a *name* via a `constexpr` variable rather than being clever with bit shifting.

Comment: @tenfour See previous

Comment: `bitset<(1 << 20)>`?

Comment: @Casey no, regardless of the name, you always have to use the clearer way. `1048576` won't be allowed to pass code review instead of `0x10'0000` or `1 << 20`